# How to get history of the native coin total issuance through API - Say DOT

Tags: polkadot-js, api

How can one download the history of a native coin total issuance, via an API - Say DOT?

Answer (score 0):

1. open polkadot apps https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/explorer
2. navigate to `developer`
3. navigate to `chain state`
4. select `balances`
5. select `total issuance`
6. if you want to know the total issuance at a specific block height, pass the block hash to the `blockhash to query at` field, e.g. I checked the block `10000000` hash `0x6c51377632106ddba379416f2ef5e24450e90cee8c78a70daa262b2ae6f27e93`

[image]

Finally, you can make these steps into a script.

Polkadot-JS API doc: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#totalissuance-u128